# Sorting a text by second elem in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting, input, struct, pipeline

Actually I wrote a  powershell script that has an  output in this "[name]: [piece]" format (name means the customer name and piece is the number of Coffe the actual customer drank.) This script is called first.ps1

For example:

Josh: 9
Sam: 13
Mark: 2

My problem is that i have to sort this output with another script just like that C: .\first.ps1 | .\second.ps1 
(second.ps1 is my sorting script)

in that case "C: .\first.ps1 | .\second.ps1" concerning the previous example my output should be like this

Sam: 13
Josh: 9
Mark: 2

I tried some code and i can succesfully read the input through pipeline but i have some sorting problems i can only sort by names i havent found anything to sort by the numbers

There is the code i tried so far

```
$input | %{

     $name=$_.split(":")[0]
     $piece=[int]$_.split(":")[1]
     Write-Output $name" "$piece

} | sort -Descending
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first script is actually not a script because it does not contain any code. ;-)  Let's call it data.
You could create a [PSCustomObject] and use its properties to sort the way you like it ... like this:

```
$data = Get-Content -Path C:\sample\data.txt

$data | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $row = $PSItem -split ':'
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name        = $row[0].Trim()
            CoffeeCount = [int]$row[1].Trim()
        }
    } |
        Sort-Object -Property CoffeeCount -Descending
```

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile i found another solution and works fine as well

```
 $input | Sort-Object {[int]$_.split(":")[1]} -Descending| %{


     $name=$_.split(":")[0]
     $piece=[int]$_.split(":")[1]
     Write-Output $name" "$piece
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Input | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ":" -Header Name, Piece | sort {[int]$_.Piece} -Descending
```

Comment: Thannk you very much!